# for loop and function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

i meet a problem and so confused.

these code can create a loop for y:

```
f1 <- function(n = 100, c=0) {
  y <- rep(0, n)

 for(i in seq(2, length = n-1)) {
 y[i] <- c + y[i-1] 
 }
return(y)
}
```

But how to create a loop like this:

```
a <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3)  
b <- c(0.4,0.5,0.6)  
y1 <- 1
y2 <- (0.1+0.4)*y1  
y3 <- (0.2+0.5)*y2+(0.1+0.4)*y1
```

I'm wondering if I need to split them into different functions and nest them together.
If you have any suggestions, please let me know, they can all help, thanks!

Comment: You don't need loops: `c(y1, cumsum(cumprod(a + b) * y1))`